# Combining cosine or sine terms into a single cosine or sine with sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm wondering how to achieve this with sympy https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30389/combining-cosine-or-sine-terms-into-a-single-cosine-or-sine

Using the identify
[image: math_eq]

Comment: Could you provide an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the guide at the link you provided, it looks like this in SymPy:

```
>>> var('a1 b1 a2 b2 w t')
(a1, b1, a2, b2, w, t)
>>> eq = a1*cos(w*t+b1)+a2*cos(w*t+b2)
>>> cs = cos(w*t), sin(w*t)
>>> xeq=collect(eq.expand(trig=True), cs)  # note trig=True
>>> B, A = [xeq.coeff(i) for i in cs]
>>> now=sqrt(A**2+B**2)*cos(w*t-atan2(B,A))
```